How is an output answer actually extracted from a quantum computer?
If you run a calculation on the quantum computer, how would the answer to the calculation be extracted from the output qubit?
e.g. If 1+1 was run, how would the answer of 2 be extracted?

Are you familiar with the quantum measurement? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics
If yes, the short answer is that in the end you just measure in a certain basis and receive a bit string (with a certain probability), depending on the algorithm the "computational output" could be either the bit string itself or statistical properties of the distribution of output bit strings.

First of all - this is a very general question and I think it would benefit from being more focused.
However, I think the key concept to understand here is that you need to encode the natural numbers (or any other data that you want to handle with some algorithms) into the qubits. Just like on the classical computer - to perform computations on the lowest level you need to convert information into strings of 0's and 1's, here you need to convert information into the states of the qubits.
In your example - if you want to add natural numbers from a given range, let's say 0-15, then you need to find a way to encode the numbers 0-15 into some quantum states. For example, you can take 4 qubits and associate the basis states $\vert 0000 \rangle$, $\vert 0001 \rangle$... with the corresponding natural numbers in binary representation, i.e.:

$\vert 0000 \rangle \longrightarrow 0$,
$\vert 0001 \rangle \longrightarrow 1$,
$\vert 0010 \rangle \longrightarrow 2$,

etc...
Then, to add two numbers you have two create a circuit that takes as an input 8 qubits. In the first 4 qubits, you encode the first number to add. In the other four qubits, you encode the second number. The circuit applies some gates in such a way that four of the qubits (let's say first four qubits) end up in the state that is associated with the addition result. Then, you measure the first 4 qubits to determine which quantum state they ended up after the algorithm has finished all its steps. If you choose the right measurement basis, you can determine which state you have measured and get the result with 100% probability.
How the measurement is performed, depends on the physical realization of the quantum computer. You can find an exemplary answer here (How are states of a qubit measured in a quantum computer?). If you are interested in how to measure the qubit in a particular physical realization, you need to make the question more precise.
